# Unable to get rid of the header and footer in Microsoft Word Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, text-editors

I am trying to remove the footer and header from Microsoft Word for Mac Version 16.53. When I click remove footer, nothing happens as in the images I have attached below. When I make the margin 0cm, nothing is fixed either.

I have attached images showing what I have tried below.

Image 1:
[image: Image 2]

Image 2:
[image: Image 1]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "remove" the header or footer parts from a Word section, you can only remove their content and change the minimum size allowed for them.

Every Word section has three header parts and three footer parts, whether or not they are displayed or have content.

What is it you are trying to achieve?

If you post a link to a sample document saved on OneDrive or DropBox here, I can probably accomplish what it is you want and tell you how to do it yourself.